# App crash when get fullResolutionImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try using my app `ALAssetRepresentation`.and when i loop om an images there are couple of image that crash the app

```
for(ALAsset *asset in _assets) {
        NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [workingDictionary setObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"];

        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

        if (!representation) {
            [workingDictionary release];
            continue;
        }
        CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];//here the app crash
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    if (!img) {
        [workingDictionary release];
        continue;
    }
    if (!img) {
        [workingDictionary release];
        continue;
    }

    [workingDictionary setObject:img forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [workingDictionary setObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyOrientation] forKey:@"orientation"];

    [returnArray addObject:workingDictionary];
    [workingDictionary release];    
}
```

in this line i get crash without any msg:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];
```

This is the crash msg

```
    Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely due to running out of memory, how big are the images that cause the crash?

Comment: picture from the image library so the need to big, couple of MB per image

Comment: It all depends what you do with them, are you using one, cleaning up the memory used (if you are adding it to any arrays etc) before moving to the next...?

Comment: So by adding it to your array you are cumulatively using up memory as the loop progresses. If not using ARC, you may wish to put an NSAutoreleasePool in and drain at each iteration to ensure the convenience method allocations get freed up quicker.

Comment: if i create NSAutoreleasePool and put [pool drain] in the end of every iteration its mean that the auto-release objects will released?

Comment: Yes, it forces a cleanup on the objects, otherwise they are released on the next run-loop, which is fine, but where you do a lot of tight iterations involving large objects you sometimes need finer control of when the pool is released.

Comment: My app is crashing if I put `NSAutoreleasePool` and `[pool drain]`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after hours of lookin for solution I found this - the best solution of too big Asset bug:

```
// For details, see http://mindsea.com/2012/12/18/downscaling-huge-alassets-without-fear-of-sigkill

#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

// Helper methods for thumbnailForAsset:maxPixelSize:
static size_t getAssetBytesCallback(void *info, void *buffer, off_t position, size_t count) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = (__bridge id)info;

    NSError *error = nil;
    size_t countRead = [rep getBytes:(uint8_t *)buffer fromOffset:position length:count error:&error];

    if (countRead == 0 && error) {
        // We have no way of passing this info back to the caller, so we log it, at least.
        NSLog(@"thumbnailForAsset:maxPixelSize: got an error reading an asset: %@", error);
    }

    return countRead;
}

static void releaseAssetCallback(void *info) {
    // The info here is an ALAssetRepresentation which we CFRetain in thumbnailForAsset:maxPixelSize:.
    // This release balances that retain.
    CFRelease(info);
}

// Returns a UIImage for the given asset, with size length at most the passed size.
// The resulting UIImage will be already rotated to UIImageOrientationUp, so its CGImageRef
// can be used directly without additional rotation handling.
// This is done synchronously, so you should call this method on a background queue/thread.
- (UIImage *)thumbnailForAsset:(ALAsset *)asset maxPixelSize:(NSUInteger)size {
    NSParameterAssert(asset != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(size > 0);

    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks callbacks = {
        .version = 0,
        .getBytePointer = NULL,
        .releaseBytePointer = NULL,
        .getBytesAtPosition = getAssetBytesCallback,
        .releaseInfo = releaseAssetCallback,
    };

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateDirect((void *)CFBridgingRetain(rep), [rep size], &callbacks);
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, NULL);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) @{
                                                                  (NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
                                                                  (NSString *)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : [NSNumber numberWithInt:size],
                                                                  (NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
                                                              });
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(provider);

    if (!imageRef) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIImage *toReturn = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CFRelease(imageRef);

    return toReturn;
}
```